# Should funding be listed under "distinctions and honours" on a PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, funding

In one of my Ph.D. applications, there's a section where I must "List any academic distinctions or honours or paricipation in olympiads etc." I don't know *exactly* what this means.

Would this include:

- A scholarship I earned to study a semester abroad at an (important) university.
- The funding I received to attend a summer school abroad? (I didn't present anything, just attended the school).
- My current MAs scholarship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, when you put together a C.V., there is a place for listing the funding that you have obtained, and these would go in that section (unless they are primarily about the honor and secondarily about the money, in which case they would go in the funding section).

For the application, if there is nowhere to list these types of funding, then I would list them in this "distinctions and honors" section.  These are significant pieces of your history, and should be listed somewhere in your application, and if this is the best fit, well, why not there?

Comment: I have all this written down in my CV, but I don't even know if there's a section to upload my documents (?). I'll follow your advice. I just wanted to know if I wasn't going to be totally off-topic.